# Making a logical statement

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Not ( every positive $n$ is bigger than $n^2$/it's square)

I thought about:

$$ \neg \forall n( (n>0) \rightarrow (n^2 < n)) $$

Is it true? I don't think it makes the right sense... Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that $\neg\forall~x.P(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists~x.\neg P(x)$, so your statement is equivalent to $\newcommand{\notimplies}{\;\not\!\!\!\implies}\exists n((n\gt 0)\notimplies (n^2\lt n))$, ie, $\exists n((n\gt 0)~\land~ (n\lt n^2))$ which is "there exists $n\gt 0$ such that $n\lt n^2$"

Comment: @PrasunBiswas and if it was $\leq$ (instead of $<$) would it still be right? thanks!